# How did L "reddere" change to E "render"?

Tags: etymology, sound-change

***[render](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/render#Etymology)***

> From Old French **rendre** ("to render, to make"), from Vulgar Latin ***rendere**, from Latin **reddere**, present active infinitive of **reddō** ("return in profit").

I just wonder whether it is a kind of sound change or just a infix "-n-"?

Comment: So you are only wondering about the n in Vulgar Latin?

Comment: Have you looked it up in the OED (render, v: Etymology)? There's an answer there.

Answer (score 4):

The "-n-" isn't a real infix (like the Proto-Indo-European infixes). It's no sound change, either.

The "-n-" is due to a mix-up ("croisement") with Latin "prendere", "prehendere" ("to take"), whence also French "prendre" (Picoche and Rolland).

Nocentini adds some other Latin verbs that could have influenced "reddere": "pendere", "vendere".

Sources:

- Jacqueline Picoche, Jean-Claude Rolland, "Dictionnaire étymologique du français", Paris 2009, Dictionnaires Le Robert, ISBN 978-2-84902-424-9
- Alberto Nocentini, Alessandro Parenti, "l'Etimologico — Vocabolario della lingua italiana", Le Monnier, 2010, ISBN 978-88-00-20781-2

Comment: Or Italian "prendere" :P